# CORS Issue with Google OAuth ASP.NET MVC sample code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using this code sample [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc) to access Google Classroom API.

I have added these in Google Cloud Platform project.

- `http://localhost:51234` as Authorized JavaScript origins
- `http://localhost:51234/AuthCallback/IndexAsync` as Authorized
  redirect URIs

A button in my webpage calls the `/Home/IndexAsync` given in above sample code link

I have just renamed my controller from `HomeController` to `GoogleClassroomController` so my button actually calls `/GoogleClassroom/IndexAsync`

In IndexAsync `else` part of the method gets executed

value of `result.RedirectUri` in else part is

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
    access_type=offline&
    response_type=code&
    client_id=abc.apps.googleusercontent.com&
    redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A51234%2FAuthCallback%2FIndexAsync&
    scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fclassroom.courses.readonly&
    state=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A51234%2FGoogleClassroom%2FIndexAsync
```

In the browser console I get 2 errors

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'<above_URL>' 
(redirected from 'http://localhost:51234/GoogleClassroom/IndexAsync')
from origin 'http://localhost:51234' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
GET <above_URL> net::ERR_FAILED
```

What am I doing wrong?

Are we not allowed to call `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` from `http://localhost:51234`?

I thought adding `http://localhost:51234` as Authorized JavaScript origins in cloud project would allow me to make this call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed It!

> my button actually calls `/GoogleClassroom/IndexAsync`

We use a custom function that makes these calls. After investigating further I found out that this custom function was internally using `$.ajax()`

Now on button's click I wrote `window.location.href = "/GoogleClassroom/IndexAsync";` and the whole "Sign in With Google" flow works correctly